# Connection string to a SQLite Database using ADODC/ADODB

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, connection, ado, adodb

Can ADODC/ADODB be used to connect to SQLite?

- If Yes- what is the connection string that can be used?
- If No- is it only to connect MS Provided DataBases?

There is a reference that can be used? `SYSTEM.DATA.SQLITE` (It is not efficient)

Can you suggest me any other references (If not ADO)?

I want to use VB.NET to connect to a SQLite backend.

Answer (score 1):

I Use ADODB Recordset to connect on SQLite database. For that You need this [provider](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) and

```
"DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & BasePath
```

for the connection string.

Beware of some restrictions : SQLite has no defined type for each field. Therefore if you misspell a date format or float, the provider with give you an error when you try to update the record.